# Add dipeptide frequency in this perl script based on sequence length

Tags: perl

I have a perl script to get the di-peptide counts (there are 400 combinations, for example- AA, AC, AD, AE...) from sequences (fasta format). But I would like to add the frequency based on the sequence lengths. I have a input with multiple sequences (myfile.fasta).

I tried to do it, but I got the wrong results. Im am not very familiar with perl.

My script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my @amino=qw/A C D E F G H I K L M N P Q R S T V W Y/;
my @comb=();

foreach my $a (@amino){
    foreach my $b (@amino){
                push (@comb,$a.$b)
        }
}
my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "myfile.fasta" , '-format' => 'Fasta');
while ( my $seq= $in->next_seq ) {
my @dipeps=($seq->seq()=~/(?=(.{2}))/g);
my %di_count=();
$di_count{$_}++ for @dipeps;
print $seq->id();
map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}:print " ",0}sort @comb;
print "\n";
}
```

I tried:

```
map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}:print " ",0}sort @comb/length;

map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}:print " ",0/length}sort @comb;
```

I also tried to define the length, such as:

```
my $seq_len = length($seq);
```

Also, I do not want to define the input file in the script, I would like to define like "perl script.pl input.fasta > result.txt". For that I should use:

```
open (S, "$ARGV[0]") || die "cannot open FASTA file to read: $!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty ugly code (should be rewritten entirely), but I think you want:

```
my $length = @dipeps;
map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}/$length:print " ",0}sort @comb;
```